# php regular expressions catch between quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have created this

```
echo "<p>".preg_replace("/\'[^\)]+\'/","",$line)."</p>";
```

to get the words between the single quotes "Privacy settings" from this line

```
$_lang['privacy.settings'] = 'Privacy settings';
```

but I get this output

```
$_lang[
```

I can't figure it out. Regex is so complicated.

Comment: 1) What is the problem? 2) Why are you using `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`? 3) Why are you trying to assign a value to `$result`?

Comment: any suggestions are welcome, preg_replace seems more direct solution

Comment: He wants the regexp to get the content out of the single quotes in the string, the value by the look of it.  See the regexp he has. preg_match() is safer as it checks, but doesn't return the value directly.

Comment: Show us what `$line` contains and the desired output of your `echo` statement.

Comment: `$line` is apparently the code line `$_lang['privacy.settings'] = 'Privacy settings';` - not sure why there is a need to get the value out using a regexp rather than including the code, but there you go.

Comment: @Gumbo He is just trying to extract a bit of what seems to be a single PHP line, perfectly possible with a regexp.  No need for a full parser if his example is correct.

Comment: This question is bad. I would vote it down, but that means losing reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The + is greedy in your regex, so it will match the string as long as it can. You can fix this with:

```
 preg_replace("/\'[^\)\']+\'/","",$line)
```

or

```
 preg_replace("/\'[^\)]+?\'/","",$line)
```

The ? in the second example tells the regex that + should not be greedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value out of that line, then try:

```
echo "<p>" . preg_replace("/^.*=.*\'(.+)\'.*$/", "$1", $line) . "</p>";
```

Comment: $_lang['privacy.settings'] = 'Privacy settings'

Comment: Really? I have tested that and it works for me.  Where `$line = '$_lang[\'privacy.settings\'] = \'Privacy settings\'';`

Comment: $_lang['privacy.viewprofile'] = 'View profile'

$_lang['privacy.everyone'] = 'Everyone'

$_lang['privacy.onlybuddies'] = 'Only buddies'

$_lang['privacy.noone'] = 'No one'

$_lang['privacy.updatesettings'] = 'Update settings'

$_lang['privacy.restoredefaults'] = 'Restore defaults'

Comment: with this code:
echo "<p>" . preg_replace("/^.*=.*\'(.+)\'.*$/", "$1", $line) . "</p>";

Comment: Are you sure $line is set correctly?